# get user's role in parse.com

Tags: android, parse-platform

I have _Role table with three roles "Role1", "Role2", "Role"
 Each role has related users Relation<_User>

I logged in as user

```
    ParseUser.logInInBackground(login, password, new LogInCallback() {
        public void done(ParseUser user, ParseException e) {
            if (user != null) {
                Log.d("Parse", "User logged in successfully");
                SharedPreferencesController.getInstance(getApplicationContext()).signInUser(login);
                Intent intent=new Intent(LoginActivity.this,ViewPagerActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
                finish();
                return;
            } else {
                Log.d("Parse", "Failed to login");
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Failed to login",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
```

Then i want to find out the role of my user, how can i do that?

i tried

```
ParseUser currentUser = ParseUser.getCurrentUser();
        if (currentUser != null) {

        } else {
            // show the signup or login screen
        }

        ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = ParseQuery.getQuery("_Role");
        query.whereEqualTo("users", currentUser);
        query.findInBackground(new FindCallback<ParseObject>() {
            @Override
            public void done(List<ParseObject> categoryAttributes, ParseException e) {
                if (e == null) {
                    for (ParseObject ob : categoryAttributes) {
                        Log.e("DATA", "ObjectID: " + ob.getObjectId());
                       // Log.e("DATA", "Column1: " + ob.getString("name"));

                    }
                } else {
                    Log.v("DATA", "Error: " + e.getMessage());
                    // Alert.alertOneBtn(getActivity(),"Something went wrong!");
                }
            }
        });
```

But categoryAttributes are empty

**I got it working**

```
if (currentUser != null) {
        ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = ParseQuery.getQuery("_Role");
        query.whereEqualTo("users", currentUser);
        query.findInBackground(new FindCallback<ParseObject>() {
            public void done(List<ParseObject> commentList, ParseException e) {
                // commentList now has the comments for myPost
                if (e == null) {
                    for (ParseObject ob : commentList) {
                        Log.e("DATA", "ObjectID: " + ob.getObjectId());
                        Log.e("DATA", "Column1: " + ob.getString("name"));
                        listener.findRole(ob.getString("name"));
                    }
                }
            }
        });
```

Comment: Change It In Code
ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = ParseQuery.getQuery("_Role");   

  query.whereEqualTo("users", ParseUser.getCurrentUser().getObjectId());

Comment: didn't help, i figured out how to solve it, watch in topic